# Problem for the existing records when adding a new property at an entity

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I added a new property to an entity and I inserted manually the corresponding
values to the existing records at the corresponding db table.
When I ask for this property for my new records (which theirs values have been assigned from the new code flow), all are fine. 
But when I ask for this property for the pre-existing records, query returns null.

I use jpql for this instance and tried both with native and non-native @Query at my repository, but the result remains the same.

*The query returns the right results at sql developer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently `I inserted manually the corresponding values to the existing records at the corresponding db table` was not successful. Maybe you have not committed the changes?

Comment: No, the query at sql developer, returns the right results..
The problem is with jpa..

Comment: Attach some code: entity column mapping, sql query, jpql query, etc

Comment: You are problably missing include in some intermediate table.

Comment: It was the sql sequence...Once again..Thank you for your answers..